# Order of Android's InboxStyle notification style not universal? How do I determine its order?

Tags: android, notifications

Let me demonstrate my answer with an image:

[image]

Looking at the image above, it is Android's default behaviour to add the latest incoming text to the **end** of an `InboxStyle` notification. So, to gain the latest text, I would simply access the last element of the `CharSequence` array.

However, in certain apps (Twitter, even the native SMS app on the Nexus 6P!) has this order completely reversed, where the latest message goes to the **top** of the stack instead.

In my app that I'm trying to create, I monitor all incoming `InboxStyle` notifications and I need a method to get the latest text that was added to each app's respective InboxStyle notification. Since this order is not universal (I'm not even sure why Android would allow this, since it's confusing that orders can be reversed on a per-app basis), how would I get it?

On some, it's the [0]th element and other's, it's the [array.length-1]th element.

Can anyone point me to the right direction in determining which order an application decides to use?

Comment: `in certain apps` it depends on how the app retrieves the data (i.e.: `ORDER BY SomeField ASC` or `DESC`)

Comment: Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: Yes, by decompiling each app. Why is it important?

Comment: I want to do this at run time. As I've said, I want to display the latest text that was added to the InboxStyle notification and display it in a log, and so far it's been a 50/50 shot.

Comment: If you want to show the latest first, then "ORDER BY SomeID DESC" is your friend. Because autoincremental IDs are always growing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Could you be more specific in getting this "order"?

Comment: You're taking your data from a database, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not even sure why Android would allow this, since it's confusing that orders can be reversed on a per-app basis

Android app developers are welcome to populate their `InboxStyle` notifications however they want. Android has no way of knowing what you think the order is supposed to be, and the developers of the apps are welcome to use an order that they think will best fit their app.

> how would I get it?

Hold onto the previous contents, and run a comparison to detect changes. Otherwise, you can't, as for all you know, the most recent one is in the middle. If that is what the app's developers want to do, that is their decision to make. You do not get a vote.

> On some, it's the [0]th element and other's, it's the [array.length-1]th element.

While those are undoubtedly the two most popular patterns, there is no requirement that new items are placed at either end.

Comment: I thought as much. I was holding off on the idea of that as that's dreadful to implement. Could you give me an example of apps that would actually place new items in the middle?

Comment: @Kyle: "Could you give me an example of apps that would actually place new items in the middle?" -- no. I would expect that to be uncommon. My point is that there is nothing stopping somebody from putting things in the middle, and they may well do that if order does not really matter to them. For example, perhaps they are iterating over a `Set` to add lines to the notification. Since a `Set` is unordered, the order of lines will be more or less random.